# Exercise regarding the mean value theorem for harmonic functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I am learning about harmonic functions and its proterpties. To understand them better I am doing some exercises.

Let $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R})^2$ be a harmonic function with $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1-x_2$ on the set {$(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x_1^2+x_2^2=16$}

Calculate f(1,2)

My attempt:
The mean value theorem for harmonic functions says that
$f(x)=\frac{1}{nV_nr^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B_r(x)} f(y) dy$

So first I tried to calculate the integral:
$\partial B_r$ is in my case the curve $\gamma(t)=4(sin(t),cos(t))$
Thus,
$\int_{\partial B_r(x)} f(y) dy=\int_0^{2 \pi} f(\gamma(t)) |\gamma'(t)| dt=4 \int_0^{2 \pi} sin(t) - cos(t) dt=0$

By the mean value theorem $f(x_1,x_2)=0$ in $B_4$ but $f(4,0)=4$ which would mean that $f$ is not continuous, which is not possible because $f$ is harmonic.

Question: Where is my mistake? Can someone show me how to calculate $f(1,2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of the circle  $ x_1^2+x_2^2=16$ is the point $(0, 0)$, so what you calculated is that $f(0, 0) = 0$, and not that $f(x_1, x_2) = 0$ in $B_4(0, 0)$.

But it is not difficult to verify that $F(x_1, x_2) = x_1 - x_2$ is harmonic in $\Bbb R^2$, so that $f-F$ is harmonic in $\Bbb R^2$ and zero on the boundary of $B_4(0, 0)$. What can you conclude?

Comment: what do you mean with $f-F$? The way you define $F$ is the same as $f$.

Comment: Do you mean that $0=max_{\partial \Omega}=max_{\overline{ \Omega}}$ and $0=min_{\partial \Omega}=min{\overline{ \Omega}}$, thus $f=F$ in $B_4(0,0)$ and further $f(1,2)=-1$.

Comment: @wanymose:  yes, exactly.

Comment: @wanymose: Does this answer your question? Please let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Yes, everything is clear. Thank you very much!